# How to make material ui slider thumb not outside of the rail

Tags: material-ui

I want to make material ui slider which the thumb is not outside of the rail like in [W3school range Slider](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp) the image is below.

[image: w3 slider]

When im using material ui slider the thumb half is outside the rail like the image below [My code with 500% zoom](https://codesandbox.io/s/continuousslider-material-demo-forked-ku5s8)

[image: mui slidervivo]

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution with tricky to make a div in ::after in rail and ::after in track [Mui Slider thumb not outside rail](https://codesandbox.io/s/continuousslider-material-demo-forked-ku5s8?file=/demo.js)

[image]